# Setting up an unit test with Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito, inject

I'm trying to set up a simple unit test with mockito for the injects. This project is just a Proof of Concept for a test my friend is making for his project.

The problem I'm having is that I get null from the method I'm calling instead of "Hello World". Also when I debug I get into a class named `MethodInterceptorFilter` that's calling the method `intercept` with `IndexOutOfBoundsExpetion` as one of its arguments.

Does someone know what I'm doing wrong?

**DAO:**

```
@Stateless
public interface DAO {
     public String helloWorld();
}
```

**DAO Implementation:**

```
@Stateless
public class DAOImpl implements DAO{

    public String helloWorld() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

**Service:**

```
@Stateless
public class Service {
    @Inject
    private DAO dao;

    public String helloWorld() {
        return dao.helloWorld();
    }
}
```

**Test:**

```
public class RandomTest {

    @InjectMocks
    Service service = new Service();

    @Mock
    DAO dao;

    @Before
    public void init(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testTest() {
        assertEquals("Hello World", service.helloWorld());
    }
}
```

By the way, I'm using IntelliJ (not sure if that matters, but saying it anyway).

Comment: First, '@InjectMocks' creates an instance of the class and injects the mocks that are created with the '@Mock' (or '@Spy') annotations into this instance, therefore try to delete the before method. Second, the '@mock' classes are classes that extend your classes and don't implement any methods, to specify a behavior for the method you need to stub it with when(...).thenReturn() If you're stubbing the void method try using '@Spy' and Lastly you need to use the runner '@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)' annotation on the Test class.

Comment: @Krystian_K your solution combined with the solution from Yoav Gur (which he just deleted) worked, thanks!

Comment: @Krystian_K if you turn your comment into an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `'@InjectMocks'` creates an instance of the class and injects the mocks that are annotated with the `'@Mock'` (or `'@Spy'`) annotations, therefore try to delete the `@Before` method, or do injects them manually but delete `@InjectMocks` annotation.

Second, the `'@Mock'` classes are classes that extend your classes and don't implement any methods (return `null`), to configure a behavior for the method you need to stub it with

```
when(...).thenReturn()
```

or if using BDD

```
given(...).willReturn()
```

If you're stubbing the void method try using a`'@Spy'` and Lastly you need to use the runner `'@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)'` annotation on the Test class if using Mockito as the JUnit test runner (which is the default runner) don't know anything about Mockito.

Answer (score 0):

The DAO class is mocked in your Service class, you need to specify the return object to mock.

```
@Test
public void testTest() {
    when(dao.helloWorld()).thenReturn("Hello World")
    assertEquals("Hello World", service.helloWorld());
}
```

Or you can use construct injection :

```
@Stateless
public class Service {

    private DAO dao;

    @Inject
    public Service(DAO dao) {
       this.dao = dao;        
    }

    public String helloWorld() {
        return dao.helloWorld();
    }
}

public class RandomTest {

    Service service;

    @Before
    public void init(){
        service = new Service(new DAOImpl());
    }

    @Test
    public void testTest() {
        assertEquals("Hello World", service.helloWorld());
    }
}
```

Or reflection, for example in Spring there is a utility class http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/util/ReflectionTestUtils.html